# Fixed string matching - large pattern set/small input rate

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, match

I have a requirement to be able to be able to compare short strings against a large (>10000) and potentially dynamic set of patterns. The patterns themselves are fixed strings which may occur anywhere in the target. The input rate would be relatively low (<100/second)

I don't need regular expressions although globbing-type wildcards might be useful in future.

The tools usually (grep, hyperscan, sift) etc are optimized for dealing with a volume of input, not a high volume of patterns, and typically standalone rather than daemons/services. Further they have more sophisticated (slower?) matching rules than I need such as regex. I suspect I may have to write my own solution.

Hence I'm asking of there are any algorithms published for this problem.

Comment: You mean finding a string in a larger string? Use [KMP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/)